# AngularJS ng-repeat view not updating after data update

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

have a some data one my page that is in a ng-repeat.
When the page and data 1st loads the data shows up.
When I move away from the page (using Angular Routing) make a change to the data (gets saved in db) then come back into the page (make call to db get new data) the ng-repeat data does not refresh. I can see the new data loading into the array and it is the new data.

I start the process on the page with

```
var sp = this;
sp.viewData = [];
sp.employee = [];
sp.ViewDataTwo = [];
$(document).ready(function () {
    var testHeader = setInterval(function () { myTimer() }, 1000);
    function myTimer() {
        if (addHeaderToken() != undefined) {
            clearInterval(testHeader);
            sp.usageText = "";
            if (sessionStorage.getItem(tokenKey) != null) {
                sp.associatedInfo = JSON.parse(getassociatedInfo());



                loadDataOne();

                loadDataTwo();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I do this because I need to get my security toke from a JS script that I have no power over changes. So I need to make sure the code has ran to get me the token.

here are the functions I call..

```
function loadPasses() {
$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = "Bearer " + addHeaderToken();
$http.get('/api/Employee/xxx', { params: { employeeId: sp.employeeId } }).then(function (data) {
sp.viewData = data.data;
for (var i = 0; i < $scope. viewData.length; i++) {
            sp.passes[i].sortDateDisplay = (data.data.status == "Active" ? data.data.DateStart + "-" + data.data[i].DateEnd : data.data[i].visitDate);
            sp.passes[i].sortDate = (data.data[i].status == "Active" ? data.data[i].DateStart: data.data[i].visitDate);
}   
});
}


function loadDataTwo () {
    $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = "Bearer " + addHeaderToken();
    if (sessionStorage.getItem(tokenKey) != null) $http.get('/api/Employee',
    {
        params: { employeeId: sp.employeeId }
    }).then(function (data) {
        sp.employee = data.data;
        var tempPassString = "";
        sp.ViewDataTwo = [];
        var totalA = 0;
        var totalU = 0;

        for (var p = 0; p < sp.employee.dataX.length; p++) {
            sp.ViewDataTwo.push(sp.employee.dataX[p].description + "(" + /** math to update description **// + ")");
            totalA += parseInt(parseInt(sp.employee.dataX[p].Anumber));
            totalU += parseInt(sp.employee.dataX[p].Bnumber));
        }
        sp.usageArr.push(" Total: " + totalA- totalU) + "/" + totalA + " Available");

        //$scope.$apply();

    });
}
```

One my view sp.viewData and sp.ViewDataTwo are both in ng-repeats. 
Works well on load.. when I go out and come back in. I see the data reloading. But the view does not.
I have hacked the Dom to get it to work for now. But I would like to do it the right way..
Any help.
I have used
$scope.$apply();
But it tells me the digest is already in process;

the views are in a template..
Please help

Comment: You've got a typo on line 3 of the second code block, `'/api/Employee/xxx` is missing an end quote.

Comment: thanks. fixed. the xxx was because I needed to remove the action name...:)

Comment: another thing I have found. if I have set a filter on the data before I change pages (angular routing) then come back in to the page I find that my filter is still there. even after I have updated the data! and if I now make a change to the data on the page "I have a button that update a value in the array" the value changes in the data. but not on the view.

Comment: Is this code supposed to be inside of an Angular controller? The fact that I see `$(document).ready()` is a big red flag. Events from 3rd party code like jQuery don't play well w/Angular's digest cycle. In this case, you shouldn't need to wait for the document to be ready at all. Angular will do that for you and start your app/controllers. Your controller can just try and load the data it needs w/out worrying if the page is fully loaded. This most likely explains all the weird stuff you see happening.

Comment: ya it is in a controller ... angular.module(model).controller('EmployeeController', function ($scope, $http, $location, $filter, $sce, $timeout, $log) {

I am going to try to take out the doc ready and have the code that is in the doc.ready in a funciton that is called at the bottom of the contoller

Comment: okay. that did not work.

Comment: something seems very very wrong with the way your controller is structure.  Can you please include the declaration of the controller and the   dependencies being injected?  Are you using Controller As syntax? Are your services located inside of the controller?  If they are, they should be standalone services and you should be passing callbacks into those services.

Comment: <div id='sp_Controller' ng-controller='spController as sp' data-bind="visible: true" class="container body-content" ng-app>
but in my angular rounting I just have the controller name with no as.
I guess I dont understand services that well. kind of new to AG.. like it and most of the time it works well for me.

Comment: I think I fixed it. it looks like I needed to do the Controller as sp in my routing as well. seems to work anyway.